# Eclipse - How to automate SVN synchronise on startup?

Tags: eclipse, svn, macros

Is it possible to automate the SVN synchronize on my workspace on Eclipse startup?  It's the first thing I do each day after firing up eclipse and it would be nice if I could automate the process.  I've had a hunt around but as yet have found no answer to this.

Failing that, is there some sort of macro option so I could at least bind it to one button click?

Running Eclipse Luna with Subclipse 1.10.9

Answer (score 0):

Select the project(s) to synchronize and use the shortcut `Ctrl` + `Alt` + `s`. That´s what I´m doing most of the time after I started eclipse.